# What method can be used to solve this system differential equations with term cos(y(t))?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have the following system
\begin{gathered}
  \frac{{dx}}{{dt}} = A*cos(y) + B*cos (b*t) \hfill \\
  \frac{{dz}}{{dt}} = A*sin(y) - Ccos (c*t) \hfill \\
  \frac{{dy}}{{dt}} = D*tan(d*t), \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}

where $$A,B,C,D,b,c,d$$ are constants.

$$t \in (0,T)$$, where $$T < \infty $$

I do not have any idea what approach to use to solve it

What I have done is as follows:
1) Integration of y
$$y = D{\left. {\frac{{ln(1 + t{an^2}(d*t))}}{{2d}}} \right|_{t\max }} - D{\left. {\frac{{ln(1 + t{an^2}(d*t))}}{{2d}}} \right|_{t\min }}$$
2)I inserted y into the equation with x
$$x = A\int {\cos \left( {D{{\left. {\frac{{ln(1 + t{an^2}(d*t))}}{{2d}}} \right|}_{t\max }} - D{{\left. {\frac{{ln(1 + t{an^2}(d*t))}}{{2d}}} \right|}_{t\min }}} \right)} dt + smth\_simple$$

But this is very fastly oscillating function and limits of integral confuse me. 
Notice that $$\left| {t\max  - t\min } \right| \leqslant 10\sec $$
P.S.  y can change only within 10 sec period, then it is constant

Probably I should assign t to tmax . And if tmin is equal to 0. I can integrate x from 0 to something. But what if tmin is not zero?

Comment: I'll edit my post to show

Comment: And what is $g$?

Comment: tg a.k.a. tan a.k.a. Tangent function

Comment: You mean the following? $$\dfrac{dy}{dt} = D \tan (d \times t)$$

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean

Comment: $$y(t) = - \dfrac{D \ln \left( \cos(d \times t)\right)}{d} + c$$

Answer (score 0):

If $g(t)$ is a known function, integrate the equation for $dy/dt$ to get $y$, then substitute the result into the equations for $dx/dt$ and $dz/dt$ and integrate.

Comment: I have added new information to my question